# Where is best place to put Custom CSS?

Tags: extjs, fieldset, extjs6.2

I need to put these CSS hacks in order to fix a blank fieldset title. Where I should put?

```
.x-fieldset-header {
    overflow: unset;
}

.x-fieldset-header-tool-default > .x-tool-toggle {
    opacity: inherit;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The best place i guess would be to regenerate the theme. If this does not work or is not possible i would define these classes inside a css-files and ensure that it gets loaded after the theme, before your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a normal CSS file and link it in the HTML file. As long as the file is listed after the ExtJS CSS file, your overrides should work.